# How it is possible to replace Cypress error message with a custom message

Tags: cypress, chai

I am trying to parse a big file and assert that a string is not included in the file using cypress. I want to replace the assertion message to keep my log clean. I have tried this:
I wraped the content as follow:

```
cy.task('parsePdf', filePath)
  .its('text')
  .then(($txt) => {
    cy.wrap($txt).as('content');
  });
```

Then I have tried to assert this using Chai `expect` and insert a custom message in two ways which both result the same:

First:

```
cy.get('@content').should(($txt) => {
  expect($txt).to.not.include(
    'text that should not be in the content',
    'Custom error message'
  );
});
```

Second:

```
cy.get('@content').should(($txt) => {
  expect($txt, 'Custom error message').to.not.include(
    'text that should not be in the content');
});
```

Result:

`Custom error message` expected `Full report content` to not include `text that should not be in the content`.

What I looking for is only logging `Custom error message` in a failure.

Expected:

`Custom error message`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps like this:

```
cy.get('@content').should(($txt) => {
  const flag = $txt.includes('text that should be in the content');
  assert.isTrue(flag, 'Custom message');
});
```